# Remove Object from Active Record Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails, I have the following Active Record Collection:

```
@products = Product.all
```

I need to loop through this collection and remove some objects from it without removing them from the database. Therefore, using

```
@products.each do |product|
    if CONDITION
        product.delete
    end
end
```

Won't work, as this will also delete the product from the database. Is there a way to remove specific products from this collection without also deleting them from the database?

Comment: Feel free to disregard this, but this is against anything such ORMs are for. ActiveRecotrd _is supposed_ to represent the objects in the database. I recommend you rethink your entire approach - do you _really_ have a good reason for such a hack?

Comment: Probably not, but I need to loop through another array as well and compare objects in both arrays to each other. I'm not sure how I would go about fitting that logic into a statement like @products = Product.where(<CONDITIONS>)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First question, if you don't want the all records, then why even return them from the DB?  Why not use a where clause to filter results:

`@products = Product.where(<CONDITIONS>)`

Second, if you insist on returning all results then filtering, use a `.reject` block:

`@products = Product.all.reject { |p| <CONDITION> }`

Comment: Thanks! I need to nest a loop through another array and compare each object in that array to each object in this array as part of the condition. I wasn't sure how I could accomplish that within @products = Product.where(<CONDITIONS>)

Comment: @Arw50452 is the comparison array and array of values (i.e. `[1,2,3,4]`) or an array of hashes (i.e. `[{value: 1}, {value: 2}, {value: 3}]`)?

Comment: The comparison array is another Active Record Array

Comment: Do you care to expand on your use case?  I have a feeling that there is a really simple solution to your problem.

Comment: Sure! I have two arrays 1) products 2) requests. The relevant fields in the requests array are: status, requestor_productid, requestee_productid, requestor_userid, and requestee_userid. If all of the following conditions are met for any given product, I want it removed from the products array

Comment: 1) the_request.status == "Approved" 2) the_request.requestor_prodid == the_product.id || the_request.requestee_prodid == the_product.id 3) the_request.requestor_id == current_user.id || the_request.requestee_id == current_user.id (In the loops, the_product and the_request represent the current object)

Comment: @Arw50452  I think you have an extremely flawed paradigm.  What is the exact relationship between Product and Request (i.e. many to many, one to many, etc)?  Also, what is the desired resulting object set?

Comment: You're probably right, very little experience working with databases. I chose to not relate requests with products, but to instead relate them to users. So in my request model it looks like: 'belongs_to :requestor, class_name: "User"
belongs_to :requestee, class_name: "User"' There are a few times (such as this one) where I need to know the products involved in a given request, so I just created fields to store each product ID

Comment: So, can the requestor and requestee have unique products on the same request?

Comment: Yeah, each the requestor and requestee will have one unique product on the same request. Each request must always have two different products.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67050/discussion-between-tagcincy-and-arw50452).

Answer (score 2):

Since Active Record Collections are arrays, you can use [reject!](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-reject-21):

```
@products.reject! do |product|
  // your_code
end
```

If `your_code` evaluates to `true`, then `product` is removed from the collection.

Comment: I get `undefined method 'reject'` when trying `reject` on my Active Record Collection. Also tried `reject!` with same result.

Comment: @ChaosFreak can you show us the complete error message?